# How to catch OutOfMemory errors on Amazon EBS (Elastic BeanStalk)

Tags: java, out-of-memory, amazon-ebs

Here's a tricky one for ya - We have a Java web application, deployed on Tomcat web servers on Amazon ElasticBeanStalk.  and we believe we have a memory leak b/c it seems that the JVM crashes every night with OutOfMemory exception.
The problem is that after the crash, EBS automatically scraps the old EC2 instance and starts a fresh one. all the logs and info get scrapped too...

I am now developing a custom CloudWatch metric to monitor the memory of the JVM (you would think there should be a prepared one...)  but that won't help me generate heap dumps

Has anyone gone through a similar problem and knows how to catch these errors on EBS?

Comment: I Somehow feel that your problem is not clear. We too have our tomcat servers on Amazon EBS, and I have seen out of memory error a couple of time, but the error crashes only tomcat and has no effect on EC2 instance. Think of your EBS instance as just a normal server. A crash in tomcat will never reboot the machine.

Comment: EBS is the elastic beanstalk, not the storage service (S3). part of the features of EBS is automatic load balancing where you define min and max instances that are automatically started and terminated depending on current traffic.  the minimum num of instances cannot be below 1 so if you have one running instance and the tomcat stops responding to HTTP requests, then EBS will automatically terminate the EC2 instance and start a new one.  isn't that the most basic feature of EBS???

Answer (score 1):

This certainly sounds like unusual EC2 (not EBS) instance behaviour.  It's interesting that if Tomcats falls over then the machine instance gets affected (in terms of stopping or terminating).

This is what I would suggest to diagnose:

1. get a running instance read to examine / play with
2. take a look at the "Termination Protection" - is this set to "enabled" or not - that could explaing the "scrapping" part of your problem (if by scrapping you mean the instance terminates and is removed).  This you can find in the properties of your EC2 instance using the AWS console.
3. take a look at the Java memory settings your Tomcat server is configured with.  Perhaps the max is (Xmx) bigger that the virtual machine has!?  If so perhaps Tomcat is literally running the machine out of memory which could explain some of the EC2-response to your out of memory.  I assume you mean "stopped" rather than "scrapped" otherwise how would you know your are getting an out of memory error?
4. if you manually kill the tomcat/java process on a working instance, does the instance stay operational (or do you get booted off and the instance gets stopped)?  If something happens simply because you stop tomcat, it means some monitoring process is kicking in and taking down the machine explicitly.
5. use the -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to produce a dump file - this will help you work out where your leak is and hopefully fix the root cause.

Good luck.  Hope that helps.

Comment: hi jowierun, sorry for the late response. this is an EBS issue, not EC2 (see my comment on the question post, EBS' load balancing is the "some monitoring process" you refer to. it runs on top of EC2 but is responsible for "scrapping" of instance and starting new one)  we never did fix the problem of instance scrapping, but we did fix the outofmemory issue by replacing the openjdk with hotspot and upgrading to latest AWS SDK.  i will look at "Termination Protection" and manually killing the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Consider a log collection service like Sumologic. The log files you specify are collected and available for analysis online. So even if your EC2 instances get replaced you can do forensics to see what happened to them